# DB2 Security - Kerberos

Tags: db2, kerberos

Does anyone know in DB2 if you can run any SQL that shows if you are connecting using a kerberos connection ?

Comment: Are you trying to determine if a User ID for a particular connection was authenticated via Kerberos, or if DB2 has been configured to allow Kerberos authentication?

Comment: I'm trying to find an SQL command I can run to see if Kerberos authenticated the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might work for; it doesn't say explicitly that the connection was authenticated via Kerberos but it implies authentication via Kerberos.

```
    SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBMADM.DBMCFG
    WHERE NAME='authentication'
    AND VALUE IN('KERBEROS','KRB_SERVER_ENCRYPT') FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I got pulled of the project for a month but back on it now and that did just the trick :)